# Building a web application to access Gmail

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-client

I am trying to build a web application which essentially traces all my subscriptions in my gmail account, something very similar to [here](https://unroll.me/). But I have no clue how to get started with the development process. Could someone suggest what tools / technology stack I need to be familiar to be able to implement something like this.

One possible case that I could think of was google app script but I want this more like a web app that I can share with people.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Vaibhav

Answer (score 1):

Google offer an API for developers that want to interact with Gmail.

Here https://developers.google.com/gmail/ you can learn how to integrate your app with Gmail.

They offer an SDK like library called **Gmail Google Client Library** in the following languages:

JAVA, .NET and Python